# Virtual host redirecting to the xampp folder, but only getting This site can’t be reached

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, localhost, virtualhost

I know I'm probably missing something simple, but I've exhausted all resources trying to get this working.

I'm running my Apache on Port:5000 and trying to direct to lsapp.dev instead of http://localhost:5000/lsapp/public/ with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/lsapp/public"
   ServerName lsapp.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried VirtualHost *:5000 but still can't get it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this on command line in your project root

```
php artisan serve --port=your_port_number
```

or do this:

edit httpd-vhosts.conf that is located in C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf and add following lines at the end of the file:

```
# VirtualHost for LSAPP.DEV

<VirtualHost lsapp.dev:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\public"
  ServerAdmin lsapp.dev
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

our apache is listening to lsapp.dev connections, but we have to configure our hosts file that allows to redirect lsapp.dev to the localhost that is located in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1   lsapp.dev
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but tried it and still not working. just wondering if my apache is running on 5000 should VirtualHost be set to 5000 instead of 80?

Comment: Done that and works pointing to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ but still doesn't resolve my issue of pointing directly to lsapp.dev, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Virtual host file like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:\laravel Task\laravel\blog" //here set your project storage path
ServerName    localhost.test.com            // set your url for your project 
<Directory "D:\laravel Task\laravel\blog">  // again set your project  storage path
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
```

set your hosts file like this

```
127.0.0.1      localhost.test.com
```

Now you can Run your project

```
 localhost.test.com
```

//OR//

If you dont want to use virtual host, then you can run your project like this

```
goto your project folder=> 
command line in your project root=>php artisan serve
your project will run in
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```